# Is there a module which has a unifying interface for Perl HTTP clients?

Tags: perl, http, cpan, www-mechanize, lwp

A couple of times now I've run into the situation where a module which only supports [HTTP::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Tiny) would benefit from allowing the user to provide her own UserAgent module ([LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent), [WWW::Mechanize::Cached](https://metacpan.org/pod/WW::Mechanize::Cached), etc)  Does a module exist which can accept a UserAgent object and then uniformly implement GET, POST etc?

A couple of use cases:

1) I want to provide my own UserAgent so that I can use [LWP::ConsoleLogger::Easy](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::ConsoleLogger::Easy) to trace the HTTP calls (useful for debugging)

2) Sometimes I want to cache requests when debugging, so I want to use [WWW::Mechanize::Cached](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Cached)

I realize that the issues above can be solved in other ways, but I think that having one module that supports several HTTP client implementations could solve a few problems nicely.

Comment: I'm unclear exactly what it is you're asking for. Are you looking for a wrapper around `LWP` that emulates `HTTP::Tiny`? Can you name some of these modules that only support `HTTP::Tiny`?

Comment: I guess I'm thinking of a wrapper that could work in either direction, depending on whether you want a response object (LWP) or a HashRef (HTTP::Tiny). I have a pull request in for PAUSE::Packages https://github.com/neilbowers/PAUSE-Packages/pull/3 and this evening I found a similar issue with MetaCPAN::Client, which used to support LWP::UserAgent, but now expects an HTTP::Tiny object https://github.com/CPAN-API/metacpan-client/pull/15  I can write the code to handle both cases for MetaCPAN::Client, but I was hoping someone else had already done the work. :)

Comment: Have you looked at http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/UserAgent . It provides pretty good logging and you can easily cache responses.

Comment: @MattGreen I haven't actually look at it closely, but I'll check it out. It doesn't solve the problem for code I already have in production, but it looks quite nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer is that such a module doesn't currently exist.  Having said that, I did come across https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Tiny::Mech, which wraps a WWW::Mechanize object and makes it return a HashRef rather than a response object.  You can use this to provide your own UserAgent to a module which is expecting an HTTP::Tiny object, while allowing you to take advantage of the mechanize features.